# Are there ways to search by attributes in excel that would be considered unstructured?

Tags: excel

Is there a way in excel to add attribute tags to rows that could be queried upon without having each tag matched to its own unique column?

Let's say we had an excel table full of US cities that each had several characteristics associated with them (size: small, medium, large; climate: hot, mild, cold; sports: has professional team, does not). Each of the city's attributes were in the same row, but not necessarily the same column, or there are only two total columns: city and a list of attributes.

I.E.

You have a table:

## unique i.d. | attributes

#### city1          | small, hot, no sports teams

#### city2          | has monument, medium

#### ....

#### cityN          | metro system, has sports teams, large

and then do a lookup where you would try to find all instances of cities with sports teams, or are considered small, or has a mild climate.

Is this possible or would you need to create a database?

I am trying to avoid having #n columns for every possible attribute since it is not guaranteed how many attributes each row would have or in what column they would exist. It would be possible to use a `vlookup(table1)` to find an instance of a keyword, but I'd like to essentially query all instances of establishments that are of medium size, not just the first entity. Is it possible to do this unstructured by having some sort of tag attribute in excel that can be queried upon?

Comment: Apply a filter -> filter for contains <attribute>

Comment: This is a good resource that explains how Excel smart tagging can be done.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/smart-tag-functionality